# GCP compute engine bandwidth bottleneck with multiprocessing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, multiprocessing, google-compute-engine

I have recently created [a tool](https://github.com/TristanBilot/bqfetch) to fetch BigQuery tables in parallel using multiprocessing backend. When this tool is running on a GCP compute engine, I do not see any bandwidth improvements when using multiple cores. However, referring to the [GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance), each vCPU can process an ingress of 2GB, for a maximum of 6 vCPUs.
The machine I'm using is an e2-standard-32 :32 vCPU, 128 GB memory, and the used bandwidth peaks at ~100MiB/S, but I was expected to ~2GB/s * 6 vCPUs.
When looking at the network bandwidth monitoring in GCP, I don't see a difference when fetching using multiprocessing.

Does anyone have an idea about how improve this bandwidth limitation imposed by compute engines?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the limitation is originating from BigQuery service and not your VM bandwidth.

Comment: Do you know what are the BigQuery limitations?

Comment: I dont know which BigQuery API are you using? but these quotas / limits  links can help: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#storage-limits and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#jobsquery_requests

Comment: Even though this answer is a guess, I agree. Achieving 100 MB/sec from BiqQuery is actually amazing in my opinion. At that speed, data is being generated faster than it can be analyzed with today's moderate hardware.